# Start onClick function in Chrome debugger

Tags: javascript, dom-events, google-chrome-devtools

How to call `onClick` function without `document.getElementById` due to I have no ID or I don't know the ID ?
e.g. I want to press a login button with the console

Comment: How do you find the login button with the console?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need id. You just need to find unique selector. It might be that it's inside a id or it's inside a unique class or if it's only button on document.

Then for triggering an event you can use either `click()` or `dispatchEvent`

```
// clicks a button inside a unique Id
document.querySelector('#uniqueId button').click();

// clicks a button directly inside a div
document.querySelector('div > button').click();

// Or dispatch a event
document.querySelector('div > button').dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
```